# C++ Dynamic Allocation Mismatch: Is this problematic?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have been assigned to work on some legacy C++ code in MFC. One of the things I am finding all over the place are allocations like the following:

```
struct Point
{
   float x,y,z;
};

...

void someFunc( void )
{
   int numPoints = ...;
   Point* pArray = (Point*)new BYTE[ numPoints * sizeof(Point) ];
   ...
   //do some stuff with points
   ...
   delete [] pArray;
}
```

I realize that this code is atrociously wrong on so many levels (C-style cast, using `new` like `malloc`, confusing, etc). I also realize that if **Point** had defined a constructor it would not be called and weird things would happen at `delete []` if a destructor had been defined.

**Question:** *I am in the process of fixing these occurrences wherever they appear as a matter of course.* However, I have never seen anything like this before and it has got me wondering. Does this code have the potential to cause memory leaks/corruption as it stands currently (no constructor/destructor, but with pointer type mismatch) or is it safe as long as the array just contains structs/primitive types?

Comment: `(Point*)new BYTE[ numPoints * sizeof(Point) ];` Someone couldn't _quite_ let go of their `malloc`, it seems...

Comment: So, why does such code exist? The fact you can't even determine if it's safe or not should be testimony that, even if it is safe (it's not, it's undefined behavior), it needs to go. Just use `std::vector<Point> pArray(numPoints);` and be done with it. I agree with tzaman, this just looks like some C programmer failed to learn C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally the code causes undefined behavior because of the pointer type mismatch in `new[]`/`delete[]`. In practice it should work fine.

The pointer type mismatch issue can easily be fixed by adding a cast to the delete-expression

```
delete [] (BYTE *) pArray;
```

If `Point` type is defined as shown in the question (i.e. with trivial constructor and destructor), then this correction solves all formal issues there are in this code. From the language point of view, the lifetime of an object with trivial constructor (destructor) begins (ends) simultaneously with its storage duration. I.e. there's no requirement to perform the actual invocation of constructor (destructor).

Comment: Why not fix the allocation instead to `new Point[numPoints];` since that's what's really happening?

Comment: In which case, use a `std::vector<Point>` and not worry about anything.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Well, that's a question to the OP. We, most likely,  don't see the entire picture. Maybe in the real code the raw buffer (a buffer of `BYTE`) is allocated early and the decision to interpret it as an array of some specific type (like `Point`) is made later, based on some run-time criterion. Who knows? Anyway, I see it as a theoretical question asked out of curiosity.

Comment: That's correct. It's really more a matter of curiosity, although the application has been known to terminate prematurely so I was interested to know if this type of thing was known to corrupt the free store. Nothing funky or cool is done at runtime; the data is just used as an array of Points. Some such occurences have already been changed to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the constructors and destructors do nothing, then you're safe.

Comment: No; deleting a pointer to the wrong type gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Technically undefined, (5.3.5.3), but practically, unless there is a very pathological implementation of delete[], nothing is going to explode.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you assure that it really does invoke a matching `delete[]` for every `new[]`, it shouldn't leak -- but if an exception might be thrown by any of the code that's been commented out, that's going to be difficult to assure (basically, you need to catch any possible exceptions, delete the memory, then re-throw the exception).

Comment: Yes, naturally, but thank you anyway. Maybe I should have indicated it more explicitly. The code here is just something contrived that I cobbled together to illustrate the allocation/deallocation. I am really more interested in understanding any potential issues that might arise as a result of the type mismatch. Thanks!

Comment: @acanaday: the other answers are correct in this respect -- if (and only if) the ctor/dtor for the type you're putting there are trivial, the type mismatch shouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to figure out why the code was written that way in the first place.  It might be simply because the programmer didn't know any better, or because they were trying to work around some funky defect int he compiler.  But there might be a real reason that you are unaware of.  If there is, then unless you understand that reason and its side effects, you may introduce a defect by changing this code.

That out of the way, and assuming there is no particular reason why the code needs to be this way now, you should be safe in changing the code to use more modern and correct constructs.

But why?  I understand the motivation to make the code more correct.  But what do you really gain by this?  If the code works the way it is now (a big assumption), then by changing the code you possibly gain the benefit of making the code more understandable to future programmers, but every line of code you change introduces the possibility for a new bug to be written.

And if finally you do decide to go ahead with the change, why stop halfway?  Consider getting rid of all the `new`s and `delete`s altogether, and replace them with `vector`s etc.